# I can't seem to understand what is creating the next line in this C program

Tags: c

(Homework question) This program is meant to capitalize the first letter of each string, however i need to put a period behind the input. I can't seem to do that as the function capital generates \n for some reason I am not aware of. Any help would be appreciated! I just need that bit, I got everything else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int capital(char s[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (i==0||(s[i-1]==' '&&s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z'))
        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s.", s);

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    printf("Please enter a line of text > ");
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    capital(s);
    return 0;
}
```

So for example I want the output to look like

```
Please enter a line of text > help me stackoverflow
Help Me Stackoverflow.
```

as opposed to it is right now

```
Please enter a line of text > help me stackoverflow
Help Me Stackoverflow
.
```

Comment: As deduplicator answered, you might try `if (s[strlen(s) - 1] == '\n') s[strlen(s) - 1] = 0;` to remove the `newline` from `s`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin except for windows newlines

Comment: Not exactly. It **does** remove the `newline`, however, DOS/Windows end-of-line is `carriage return / newline` (`0xd 0xa`). In that instance you would need `if (s[strlen(s) - 2] == '\r') s[strlen(s) - 2] = 0; else if (s[strlen(s) - 1] == '\n') s[strlen(s) - 1] = 0;` (but you already knew that -- so good comment)

Answer (score 7):

[`fgets`](//man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) preserves the newline.

> #### 7.21.7.2 The fgets function
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> 2 The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
> from the *stream* pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional
> characters are read after a **new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A
> null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

---

Some other things:

1. It's a bad idea to use strlen in the termination condition.
   It makes your algorithm quadratic, unless your compiler succeeds in determining that the string is not shortened in the loop, and you really don't want to depend on it.

   Test `s[i]` instead.
2. Be aware that `toupper` only works properly in some locales with single-byte character-sets.
   (Same for `iswhite`, which you probably wanted to use for checking whitespace.)

   Anyway, as you are already checking for 'a'-'z' before calling it, why don't you just finish it?

   ```
    if ((!i || s[i-1]== ' ') && s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z')
        s[i] += 'A' - 'a';
   ```

   (BTW: Your condition was slightly curious.)

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) (emphasis mine)

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and *included in the string* copied to str.

So the `\n` is already on your string when you try to append the period. You either need to insert the period just before the end of the string, or remove the `\n`, which will be left as an exercise for the reader.